# How to create multiple accounts with user input using class constructor

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have created this bank account class constructor in java that makes it possible to create any number of accounts. This is part of an assignment for my java course. However, I have to manually specify each attribute of the accounts (Account ID, and balance).
What I want to do is get the user involved. For example, the user should be prompted if they want to create a new account. If they answer yes, they should be able to set the account number (weird? I know) and the account balance. The program should then create the account for them using the inputs.
I already have the options for checking account balance, making deposit or withdrawal that is working as expected, however, I want it to work for multiple accounts created. For example, the user is prompted if they want to create new account, and if yes, specify account number and balance. If they want to check the status of existing accounts, the program should give them an option of which account they want to get info about. Then the program should go through the routine behavior of displaying the prompts that I have already created.
It would also be nice if the code lets the user to create multiple accounts at once. For example:

- In main, create an array of 10 Account objects with id 0 - 9 and starting balance of $100 each.
- Prompt the user for an id.
- Prompt the user for an amount to withdraw or deposit (or both).
- Modify that Account, then print its balance.

Here is my existing class constructor portion:

```
// Bank account class creator 

public class Account {
    // Create attributes for the Account class
    private int id; 
    private double balance;
    private double withdraw;
    private double deposit;
    private static double annualRate;
    private static String dateCreated;
    
    // Create default constructor
    Account() {
        id = 0;
        balance = 0;
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        dateCreated = date.toString();
        annualRate = 4.5;
    }
    // Create constructor which allows input values
    Account(int accountId, double accountBalance) {
        this.id = accountId;
        this.balance = accountBalance;
    }
    // Getter for account ID
    int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    // Getter for account balance
    double getBalance() {
        return this.balance;
    }
    // Getter for annual interest rate
    double getAnnualRate() {
        return this.annualRate;
    }
    // Getter for date
    String getDate() {
        return this.dateCreated;
    }
    // Getter for monthly interest amount
    double getMonthlyInterest() {
        return  this.balance * this.annualRate / 1200;
    }
    // Getter for annual interest amount
    double getAnnualInterest() {
        return  this.balance * this.annualRate / 100;
    }
    // Validate deposit (filter negative numbers out)
    double deposit(double depositAmount) {
        if (depositAmount > 0) {
            this.balance = this.balance + depositAmount;
            return this.balance;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    // Validate withdraw (filter negative numbers out)
    double withdraw(double withdrawAmount) {
        if (withdrawAmount > 0) {
            this.balance = this.balance - withdrawAmount;
            return this.balance;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    // Validate ID (filter negative numbers out)
    void setId(int accountId) {
        if (accountId > 0)
            this.id = accountId;
        else
            this.id = 0;    
    }
    // Validate interest rate (filter negative numbers out)
    void setAnnualRate(double currentInterest) {
        if (currentInterest > 0)
            this.annualRate = currentInterest;
        else
            this.annualRate = 0;    
    }
    // Setter for balance
    void setBalance() {
         this.balance = this.balance + this.deposit - this.withdraw;
    }

}
```

Here is the main code that uses the constructor to create accounts:

```
// Bank account tester 

import java.util.Scanner; // import java Scanner utility
public class TestAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account1 = new Account();           // Create a new account
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     // Create a Scanner object
        
        System.out.println("1. Show balance");      
        System.out.println("2. Deposit funds");
        System.out.println("3. Withdraw funds");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
        
        int userInput = input.nextInt();            // Get input from the user
        
        while (userInput != 4) {                    // Start of loop to check for exit condition
    
            if(userInput == 1) {
                // Display account balance, monthly interest and current date
                System.out.printf("Balance: $%.2f\n" , account1.getBalance());
                System.out.printf("Monthly interest $%.2f\n" , account1.getMonthlyInterest());
                System.out.println("Date created: " + account1.getDate());
            }
                
            else if (userInput == 2) {
                // Deposit funds to account
                System.out.println("Enter amount to deposit:");
                double inputAmount = input.nextDouble();
                account1.deposit(inputAmount);
            }
            else if (userInput == 3) {
                // Withdraw funds from account
                System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw:");
                double inputAmount = input.nextDouble();
                account1.withdraw(inputAmount);
            } else
                // Prompt the user to input option choice if they input invalid option
                System.out.println("That is not a valid choice. Please enter a valid choice; ");
            // Continue displaying the options until the user's option is to exit 
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("1. Show balance");
            System.out.println("2. Deposit funds");
            System.out.println("3. Withdraw funds");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");
            userInput = input.nextInt();    // Continue getting inputs until user chooses to exit
            
        }
        input.close(); // close the input method
        // Display an exit message when the user chooses to exit
        System.out.println("Thank you for using our banking software ");
    }
}
```

I would also appreciate if you could point out to any error or redundancy in my code, for example incorrect use of static or redundant "this." keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Few thing regarding of possible refactoring:

Invalid use of static in *Account*:

> the keyword static indicates that the particular member belongs to a type itself, rather than to an instance of that type.
> Blockquote

*annualRate* and *dateCreated* should NOT be static as it means that these values will be shared among all instances of *Account* class.

Its possible to remove duplicated code for print of program options:

```
private void printHelp() {
    System.out.println("1. Show balance");
    System.out.println("2. Deposit funds");
    System.out.println("3. Withdraw funds");
    System.out.println("4. Exit");
}
```